# Setting value of an objects property using dot notation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, associative-array

I understand my title might be a little vague, but bear with me.

I was playing with localStorage, so I made some really simple thing I could just mess with in the console of Firefox.

I had the following code:

```
function saved(data) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(data) !== null) {
        return localStorage.getItem(data);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var Player = {
    canOpenDoors: false ? saved('canOpenDoors') == false : saved('canOpenDoors'),
}

Player.setAbility = function(ability, value) {
    Player.ability = value;
    localStorage.setItem(ability, value);
}

Player.getAbility = function(ability) {
    return Player[ability];
}

console.log(Player.canOpenDoors);
```

The part in question here is `Player.ability = value` inside the `Player.setAbility` function. Obviously, I'm expecting it to treat the `ability` part as the parameter passed into the function, so that if I do `Player.setAbility('canOpenDoors', true)` it sets `Player.canOpenDoors` to `true`. What I suspect is actually happening is it's setting `Player.ability` to `true` instead, as if I want ability to actually be a key of the object.

I can make it work by doing:

```
Player.setAbility = function(ability, value) {
    Player[ability] = value;
    localStorage.setItem(ability, value);
}
```

But unless I've been misinformed, it's not 'correct' to set values of an object as if it was like an associative array. Is there a way I can do this via dot notation, or perhaps I'm missing the point and there's a way to do this specifically for objects?

Comment: `Player.ability = value` – here you assign property of Player named 'ability'. To access property, which name stored in variable, you can use only square bracket notation `Player[ability] = value`.

Comment: You've been misinformed. It is perfectly fine to use square bracket notation to do what you're doing, and in fact would be the preferred way of doing it in this situation (over eval, etc), verbose ES5 methods etc. JavaScript doesn't *have* a concept of associative array's, so in future I'd be wary of listening to wherever you're getting this advice from!